How terraform can throw dynamic error if a parameter exists in configuration json file
We are decoding a json configuration file in our terraform main.tf within locals{}.
input_client_config = jsondecode(base64decode(local.client_config_base64))

Now we need to check for few parameters which must not exist in this json. If exist, throw dynamic error during planning stage. I tried below way. But this did not throw any error when I provided users in clien_config file.
locals{

input_client_config = jsondecode(base64decode(local.client_config_base64))
error_flag = can(local.input_client_config.user) == true ? true : false

}

resource "null_resource" "throw_error" {
  count = local.error_flag ? 1 : 0
  triggers = {
    always_fail = "User must not be there in client config file"
  }
}


An aside, but the == true ? true : false here is superfluous.

You can implement a validation check as a precondition of a resource that needs to be validated.
Example
main.tf
locals {
  input_client_config = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/client-config.json"))

  # Sets user_config=null if user property is not present in client config file
  user_config = lookup(local.input_client_config, "user", null)
}

resource "null_resource" "user_config" {
  lifecycle {
    precondition {
      condition     = local.user_config == null
      error_message = "User must not be there in client config file"
    }
  }
}

client-config.json
{
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "admin",
    "email": "admin@localhost"
  }
}

Running terraform plan:
Error: Resource precondition failed

  on main.tf line 13, in resource "null_resource" "user_config":
  13:       condition     = local.user_config == null
    ├────────────────
    │ local.user_config is object with 3 attributes

User must not be there in client config file


Another important detail is to make sure that the precondition is associated with whatever resource should have its actions blocked by the error message, or alternatively the resources that should be blocked must depend on the resource that has the precondition. Otherwise it's possible that Terraform will begin working on something else before it checks the precondition, making the precondition less effective.

@RuiJarimba thank you, I tried to implemented as suggested above and got below error:  Error: Unsupported block type
│
│   on main.tf line 137, in resource "null_resource" "user_config":
│  137:     precondition {
│
│ Blocks of type "precondition" are not expected here.

@D.S. preconditions and postconditions are are available from Terraform v1.2.0 and later. Which version are you using?

@RuiJarimba ok, tfe version is 1.0.8 for me. Then what alternative can I use?

@D.S. Terraform v1.0.8 was released almost 3 years ago (Sep 29, 2021). Is there any good reason for not upgrading it?

Upgrading is not in my control. Anyhow could you please let me if any alternative for 1.0.8.
